# Java radiobutton if else

Tags: javascript

I am currently new to web development, how do you get the total value of the chosen radio buttons and store it in an array then the link or page would be different base on the total value. Is it possible in javascript? let's say that the total values of the selected buttons is 50 then it will go to page1 if not it will go to page2 and so on.

```
    <HTML>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
    </head>
    <div class="wrap">
    <h1 class="likert-header">Likert Scale survey</h1>
    <form action="">
    <label class="statement">Q1.</label>
    <ul class='likert'>
    <li>
    <input type="radio" name="likert" value="25">
    <label>Strongly agree</label>
    </li>
    <li>
    <input type="radio" name="likert" value="25">
    <label>Agree</label>
    </li>
    <li>
    <input type="radio" name="likert" value="strong_agree">
    <label>Neutral</label>
    </li>
    <li>
    <input type="radio" name="likert" value="-25">
    <label>Disagree</label>
    </li>
    <li>
    <input type="radio" name="likert" value="-25">
    <label>Strongly disagree</label>
    </li>


    </ul>
    <label class="statement">Q2.</label>
    <ul class='likert'>
        <li>
    <input type="radio" name="likert" value="25">
    <label>Strongly agree</label>
    </li>
    <li>
    <input type="radio" name="likert" value="25">
    <label>Agree</label>
    </li>
    <li>
    <input type="radio" name="likert" value="strong_agree">
    <label>Neutral</label>
    </li>
    <li>
    <input type="radio" name="likert" value="-25">
    <label>Disagree</label>
    </li>
    <li>
    <input type="radio" name="likert" value="-25">
    <label>Strongly disagree</label>
    </li>
    </ul>
    <button class="clear">Clear</button>
    <button class="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
   </form>
   </div>
   </HTML>
```